# Forge design automation app stack at "workitem started:

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am using learn.forge.designautomation-master sample code. Using VS 2019, ngrok as described in forge tutorial.So far did not do any mistake knowingly. Please see the screen shot. The app is stack as the screen shot.

What could be the reason ? I have my own app bundle and similar app, having same trouble. So I thought I should try with forgesample, and bang same error here. I guess I am doing some common mistake, as a beginner. Please give me some clue, what could cause it.

[image: image/screenshot of error]

Comment: can you please confirm the ngrok app is running and if the env var is properly set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your screenshot it looks like you have successfully posted your workitem to Design Automation for Revit, but that you are having trouble getting your workitem results back.

Please double-check your steps around the ngrok.io URL that is used as the FORGE_WEBHOOK_URL environment variable.  The FORGE_WEBHOOK_URL environmental variable needs to be valid and correct for the results to get back to you.

Thanks!
Michael

Comment: Hi Michael, You are correct, my ngrok was not connecting properly. Now it is working perfectly! :) Many thanks for the reply.

Comment: glad it's working @nayran, please remember to "accept as answer" :) thank you!

Comment: I forgot to accept answers, From now on, I will, for sure :)